# Wordpress Subdomain Issue

Tags: wordpress, server, subdomain

That is really strange – this only occurs when you try to go directly to https://kellieworks.ca/membership/, when you click Join or Join The Party within the navigation tab, it goes to the correct page; if you refresh the Membership page or go to the direct URL, the old page loads.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser cache and and try again. If you have any cache plugin installed then clear cache from there too.